# How to listen for browser window close event in Angular Protractor

Tags: angularjs, browser, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I am trying to write e2e tests for logging into my app with auth0. When the user inputs their credentials and clicks to log in, auth0 loads a popup which I assume is verifying their details and when this closes, I know if the login attempt has succeeded or failed. Currently to get the test to work I am calling

```
browser.sleep(4000).then(....
```

To make it wait 4s for the popup to open and process their data and then close. But that seems like a bad way to do it. Ideally I'd like to listen for the close event on the popup window, but I am not sure how to do this? Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using wait() function of protractor to check for the presence of elements. Here's the link to it - [Protractor wait](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) and then verify the element's presence by its visibility or invisibility. Below is the sample -

```
var ele = //you element's locator
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ele),10000).then(function(){
//verify the body details of popup
  browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(ele),10000).then(function(){
    console.log('element opened and closed');
  });
});
```

Alternatively, if the pop up that you get is an alert then you can check for the presence of alert and then verify things as you want.  [More info on alert](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.alertIsPresent). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Using browser.wait() did fix it for me, but I couldn't check for an element as there seems to be some sort of issue with a popup if you call browser.switchTo() on the popup and then it closes itself - I was getting a NoSuchWindowError. Instead I checked the length of the browser.getAllWindowHandles() Array and that seems to work fine.